# Using PowerMockito to mock method with void return-type: "invalid void parameter"

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, powermock

I am having some trouble trying to unit test java code that at some point calls native methods. Basically, I am trying to use `PowerMockito` to mock the class that will eventually call native. I was able to mock non-void methods just fine, but I keep getting compilation errors when I try to mock a method of void return type. Here is an example of the code I'm trying to test:

```
public class ClassThatCallsNative {

    void initObject(ByteBuffer param1, int param2) {
        //calls native
    }

    int getId(int param1) {
        //calls native
    }
}
```

I have this code in my test class:

```
PowerMockito.when(mClassThatCallsNative.getId(Mockit.anyInt())).thenReturn(0);
```

This line of code compiles just fine, however the following line is where I get compilation error:

```
PowerMockito.when(mClassThatCallsNative.initObject(Mockit.any(ByteBuffer.class), anyInt())).doNothing();
```

The error message just says invalid void parameter and points to .initObject.
Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: It doesn't really have anything to do with calling native, you're right. I was just trying to add context to the problem i'm having.

Comment: Related task-context in the question, problem-context in the title and tags.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are trying to mock method which returns void, you simply can't call it inside when() method. This is because PowerMockito.when() methods expects T methodCall but got void, this is the reason for compilation failure.
Instead you should use this syntax:

```
PowerMockito.doNothing().when(mClassThatCallsNative).initObject(any(ByteBuffer.class), anyInt())
```

any() and anyInt() methods are part of Mockito class.

Comment: what is mClassThatCallsNative here? what if initObject method is static?

Answer (score 0):

For void methods, you need to use below one

PowerMockito.doNothing().when(mClassThatCallsNative.initObject(Mockit.any(ByteBuffer.class), anyInt()))

Comment: Same error: void type not allowed here, for the first parameter

Answer (score 0):

Figured out what the problem was, at last. Turns out I needed the instance of ClassThatCallsNative in order to mock it's methods. What was happening before is that the object was being initialized inside a constructor call, but when I created another constructor that takes ClassThatCallsNative as a parameter, and set my instance to that instead, everything worked fine.

Thank you anyways!

Comment: Also, the line of code for mocking void methods is this: PowerMockito.doNothing().when(mClassThatCallsNative).initObject(Matchers.<ByteBuffer>any(), Mockito.anyInt());